# Flurl calling IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, flurl

I'm attempting to call Identity Server 4 with Flurl

Im getting a 400 back from the ID server.
The credentials etc work when I make the call with PostMan or with the methods available in IdentityModel.Client.

I am unsure about the Post i.e. PostUrlEncodedAsync
As you can see I have tried various combinations.

This.. does not work

```
var address = "http://localhost:8027/connect/token";
var x = await address
.WithBasicAuth("clientName", "secretValue")
.SetQueryParams(
    new
    {
        GrantType = "client_credentials",
        Scope = "requiredScope"
    }
)
.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { });
//.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, null, CancellationToken.None);
//.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, y);
```

This.. does.

```
var apiClientCredentials = new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest()
{
    Address = "http://localhost:8027/connect/token",

    ClientId = "clientName",
    ClientSecret = "secretValue",
    Scope = "requiredScope"
};

var client = new HttpClient();

var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(apiClientCredentials);
if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
}
```

I can see that deep doen inside 'RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync' it does parameters.Add to add grant type and scope hence I have added those as params.

Have also tried adding the client id and secret to the query params.

Same 400 message.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the difference is that IdentityModel knows to serialize those `ClientCredentialsTokenRequest` property names like `ClientId` and `GrantType` to snake-case, i.e. `client_id` and `grant_type`, as required by OAuth2. When you hand Flurl an anonymous object, it just serializes the property names exactly as-is. To make it work with Flurl you can either create a class and decorate it with [Json.NET serialization attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm), or (what I typically do) keep it simple take some liberties with C# property name conventions:

```
.SetQueryParams(
    new
    {
        grant_type = "client_credentials",
        scope = "requiredScope"
    }
```

Comment: I havent got it working yet but thanks for reminding me about serialisation attributes.

Comment: address.Post with  FormUrlEncodedContent using your suggestion of snake casing the keys worked. Cheers